# How to catch exception thrown by IEnumerable outside of my code

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I have encountered an issue with aspnet core mvc error handling. I have properly set up exception handling in my startup code (it works when exceptions are thrown while executing code within controllers methods), but I am getting exception which is not being handled by my handlers and it is not being logged either.

But in one case I am returning an enumerable with anonymous objects to the conrtoller method. Then it is being passed to the Ok method to be returned as JSON. When it is being enumerated, it turns out that one of the objects cannot be created due to NullReferenceException. This exception is thrown when collection is enumerated, after my controller method returned Ok. It is not being registered by any excpetion handling mechanism that I tried:

- UseExceptionHandler,
- builder.AddMvcOptions(o => { o.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter(logger)); });

Example code for clarity:

```
// in some repo class
public bool IsEnabled(int i)
{
    if ( i == 50)
    {// this is to repro only, in reality it is caused by bad data, and
     // we want the exception to be thrown if such data came - we just   
     // want to catch and log it
        throw new NullReferenceExcpetion(); 
    }
    return true;
}

// in some repo class
IEnumerable<object> GetObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        yield return new { Id = i, Enabled = IsEnabled(i) };
    } 
}

// in some controller that has [Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("objects")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetObjects()
{
    var objects = await someRepo.GetObjects();

    return this.Ok(objects);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could catch such exception, except changing return type to IList?

Comment: returning an IList is not a bad idea here.

Comment: If you enumerate before returning `Ok`, the error will be triggered sooner and maybe get logged. `var objects = await someRepo.GetObjects().ToArray();` The collection must be enumerated anyways for serialization.

Comment: And this is what I did now, to solve it - I am enumerating before Ok - returning IList from the repository method. But what I am worried about it that this may repeat again, and again someone will have to find out that there is no logs from the error, and try to repro with preprod data. The exception was totally invisible in this case - I was getting only http/json errors - depending on the browser.